# Training network with synthetic dataset

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network

before i have never working with synthetic dataset, but in my project I do not have enough dataset, that is why I want use hull synthetic dataset to my network. It is posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes sure, it is possible and widely used in machine learning when there is lack of dataset.